# MySQL - indexes are working on the staging server, but don't on production

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I am doing some geographical calculations with data in a table, so I added there indexes. There are 2 indexes, one on the column called `latitude`, the next one on `longitude`.

Then, I needed to copy this database (300k records) from staging on the production server. So I exported  this table from staging and imported it on the production server.

But when I ran there queries, it's very slow, like the indexes are not in use. So I tried to remove them and create them again:

```
CREATE INDEX index_hotels_on_latitude_and_longitude ON hotels(latitude, longitude)
```

The index was created in `0.80s`. But when I ran again some queries, the results were again very slow, like if the indexes are ignored again.

What's wrong here? How can I even debug this issue?

The databases are equal (the same data as on production as on the staging server).

Thank you guys for your time.

**EDIT:**

Here's the query:

```
@hotels = Hotel.includes(:services).within(distance, origin: in_city).order("distance ASC")
```

This query generate following SQL:

```
SELECT (ACOS(least(1,COS(0.5943236044502174)*COS(-2.0637416211957023)*COS(RADIANS(hotels.latitude))*COS(RADIANS(hotels.longitude))+
 COS(0.5943236044502174)*SIN(-2.0637416211957023)*COS(RADIANS(hotels.latitude))*SIN(RADIANS(hotels.longitude))+
 SIN(0.5943236044502174)*SIN(RADIANS(hotels.latitude))))*3963.1899999999996)
 AS distance,hotels.* 
FROM `hotels` WHERE ((
 (ACOS(least(1,COS(0.5943236044502174)*COS(-2.0637416211957023)*COS(RADIANS(hotels.latitude))*COS(RADIANS(hotels.longitude))+
 COS(0.5943236044502174)*SIN(-2.0637416211957023)*COS(RADIANS(hotels.latitude))*SIN(RADIANS(hotels.longitude))+
 SIN(0.5943236044502174)*SIN(RADIANS(hotels.latitude))))*3963.1899999999996)
 <= 100.0))
ORDER BY distance ASC
```

(I am sorry, I am not sure how to make the big query easier to read)

Comment: Please edit your question with the query you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You say there are *two* indexes.  That would suggest that you need:

```
CREATE INDEX index_hotels_on_latitude ON hotels(latitude);
CREATE INDEX index_hotels_on_longitude ON hotels(longitude);
```

A composite index is different from two indexes.

Comment: Thank you, I just tried to create these indexes, but it didn't help, still the same time. I added the query to the OP.

Comment: @user984621 . . . Your query does not look like it would use indexes on either server.  I suspect the performance difference is due to something else.